# Understanding the use of "active warden" in scientifc texts

Tags: meaning-in-context, science

I've been reading some computer science papers, and in particular papers I see the use of the phrase "active warden" such as:

- If an active warden drops all delayed packets, then it will potentially drop packets that still can be useful for voice reconstruction.
- With an active warden, it is important for the methods to be as robust as possible to transformations such as lossy encoding and band-pass filtering

Having googled the definition of the word, I have no idea how it fits these phrases.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd also included the definition of _active warden_.

Comment: *active warden* seems to be a term of art for a block of functionality similar in tone to *network firewall* *packet filter* etc.  From the noun *warden* we can deduce that it’s goal is to keep things either in or out.  *active* (as opposed to passive) means it is actually doing something while the system is running- inspecting packets for example and making decisions and not just   putting up a wall.

Comment: The quotations come from two papers on steganography, both concerned with how to hide communications in audio--the problem being that doing so may distort the sound. Thus "a means for secure, discreet communications through a monitored, hostile channel." The active warden handles the insertion of the hidden message.